# prevent multiple AJAX-Calls in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I tried to accomplish a “real” MVC with PHP, jQuery and AJAX.

I have a front end (Web-GUI, jQuery) that triggers AJAX-Calls to a back end (PHP & MySQL) and re(renders) the front end based on the result of those AJAX-Calls.

For example:

A list of usernames (from Active Directory) gets displayed on the Front-End and if you click on one of them, an AJAX-Call is triggered that results in a database-operation in the backend.

When the AJAX-Call is completed, the page gets rerendered based the result of the database-opereation in the back end on the new “state” of the model.

Everything works fine except that when a Web-GUI-user for example clicks many users of that list of usernames really quickly in a row, the Web-GUI either freezes or I get layout-errors like messed up HTML-tables ...

What I would like to have is to prevent the user from clicking those users to fast in a row or catch it by my application somehow if he does.

I searched the web for days and tried nesting the AJAX calls by placing the next call into the success-function of the previous call.

```
$.ajax({

    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    url: '/index.php/ssadmin/delUser',
    data: {userName: userName, repoName: repoName, locationName: locationName}

}).success(function () {

    // DO STUFF ...

    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url:  '/index.php/ssadmin/changePermissions',
        data: { userName: userName, permissions: "r", repoName: repoName, locationName: locationName }

    }).success(function( returnData ) {

        // DO STUFF ...

    }).fail(function () {

        console.log("AJAX FAILED");

    });

}).fail(function () {

    console.log("AJAX FAILED");

});
```

I also tried webworkers. To no avail.

```
function userInfo(ouName, userName, repoName, locationName, locationType) {

    var workerUserInfoOU = $.work({file: '/js/workerUserInfoOU.js', args: { ouName: ouName }});
    var workerUserInfoRepo = $.work({file: '/js/workerUserInfoRepo.js', args: { userName: userName, repoName: repoName, locationName: locationName     }});

    $.when(workerUserInfoOU, workerUserInfoRepo).done(function(userInfoOU, userInfoRepo){

        //DO STUFF

    });

}//end userInfo
```

It would very much appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Best Regards
Nero

Comment: Use jQuery Deferred objects

Answer (score 1):

method 1, use blocked request:

```
$.ajax({ async: false, type: 'POST', ... })
```

method 2, use a variable to indicate whether the last request is finished.

method 3, disable the button which the user just clicked, and enable it when the ajax request finishes.